# How to make wordnik api stop throwing exceeded access limits error

Tags: javascript, json, api, wordnik

I am trying to use the Wordnik API for a project in JS.

When playing around with the API I think I made to many requests and now I get "exceeded access limits" error whenever I make a request.
Is there anything I can do to make the error go away or should I just wait for it to fix itself?

Here are the settings I set ([url](http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/apple/definitions?limit=1&includeRelated=false&sourceDictionaries=all&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5)):

```
    word: apple
    limit: 1
    partOfSpeech: <none>
    includeRelated: false (default)
    useCanonical: false (default)
    includeTags: false (default)
```

This is the response I get:

```
{
  "message": "exceeded access limits",
  "type": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to make sure that you are using your own API key, and *not* the key that is used for the Wordnik API documentation. :)

If you haven't received your key by email (after signing up for Wordnik and requesting one at http://developer.wordnik.com), check your Wordnik user settings page; log in on Wordnik.com and go to:

https://www.wordnik.com/users/edit

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes, just **re-enter** the api key in the code, and then restart the app, browser or whatever you're testing the api on; and this somehow fixes it

Answer (score -1):

This just started to happen to me today.   It was previously working fine for the last 2 weeks. There's no way I've exceeded the limit since we have not released the app yet.   I'm thinking it's a bug server side.